# Can I turn this requirement into a macro?

Tags: c, macros, keil, 8051

I have C programs with decrementing software counters. If for instance I want to blink an led every 2 seconds I can do:

```
if(!ledT) { 
    ledT = 200;
    // code
    // code
    // code 
}
```

Because I always do the exact same combination with every counter, I tend to type it one line.

```
if(!ledT) { ledT = 200;
    // code 
    // code 
    // code  
}
```

For the entire if-line I'd like to use a macro instead. So the code would look something like:

```
expired(ledT, 200) {
    // code 
    // code 
    // code 
}
```

I use something similar in my state machine code for the entry state.

```
if(runOnce) { runOnce = false;
    // code 
    // code 
    // code
```

Desired syntax:

```
entryState {
    // code 
    // code 
    // code
```

.

```
#define entryState if(runOnce) { runOnce = false; // this ofcourse cannot work But something like this is what I want.
```

I've made several attempts but I got nowhere. The problem is that the `{` is somewhere in the middle of the macro and I want to type a `{` behind the macro because as we all know, no code editor can live with an unequal number of `{` and `}`.

```
expired(ledT, 200); // expired is macro, not function
    // code
    // code
    // code
}
```

So this is out of the question.

Whilst reading about macros, I've read something interesting about using: do ... while(0). This 'trick' abuses the compiler's optimization feature to create a certain macro, which would otherwise be impossible.

[This site](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-using-do-while-0-in-macros)

sheds some light about this manner.

Is there a way to use some kind of 'macro trick' to achieve what I want?

So again, that is transforming:

```
// this
if(runOnce) {
    runOnce = false;
    // code
    // code
    // code

// into this
entryState {
    // code
    // code
    // code

// and this:
if(!someTimer) {
    someTimer = someInterval;
    // code
    // code
    // code

// must be transformed into:
timeExpired(someTimer, someInterval) {
    // code
    // code
    // code
```

And an answer like "No, it simply cannot be done" will also be accepted (providing you know what you are talking about)

EDIT:
I need to add an addition because not everybody seems to know what I want, the last given answer is not even aimed at the specific problem at hand. Somehow toggling IO suddenly became important? Therfor I altered my code examples to better illustrate what the problem is.

EDIT2:
I agree that the the timeExpired macro does not improve readability at all

To show that some macros can improve readabilty I'll give a snippet of a state and a state machine. This is how a generated state looks like in my code:

```
State(stateName) {
    entryState {
        // one time only stuff
    }
    onState {
        // continous stuff
        exitFlag = true; // setting this, exits the state
    }
    exitState {
        // one time only stuff upon exit
        return true;
    }
}
```

Currently in place with these macros:

```
#define State(x) static bool x##F(void)
#define entryState if(runOnce) 
#define onState runOnce = false;
#define exitState if(!exitFlag) return false; else
```

I think I should I should exchange `return true;` in the states by `EXIT` or something prittier.
And the state machine which calls these States looks like:

```
#undef State

#define State(x) break; case x: if(x##F())
extern bit weatherStates(void) {
    if(enabled) switch(state){
        default: case weatherStatesIDLE: return true;

        State(morning) {
            if(random(0,1)) nextState(afternoon, 0);
            else            nextState(rain, 0); }

        State(afternoon) {
            nextState(evening, 0); }

        State(evening) {
            if(random(0,1)) nextState(night, 0);
            else            nextState(thunder, 0); }

        State(night) {
            nextState(morning, 0); }

        State(rain) {
            nextState(evening, 0); }

        State(thunder) {
            nextState(morning, 0); }

        break; }
    else if(!weatherStatesT) enabled = true; 
    return false; }
#undef State
```

The only thing which is not generated are the 'if' and 'else' before the 'nextState()' functions. These 'flow conditions' need filling in.

If a user is provided with a small example or an explanation, he should have no difficulty at all with filling in the states. He should also be able to add states manually.

I'd even like to exchange this by macros:

```
extern bit weatherStates(void) {
        if(enabled) switch(state){
            default: case weatherStatesIDLE: return true;
```

and

```
break;} }
    else if(!weatherStatesT) enabled = true;
    return false;}
```

Why would I do this? To hide irrelevant information out of your display. To remove alot of tabs in the state machine. To increase overal readability by using a simple syntax. Like with 3rd library functions you need to know how to use the code rather to know how the function does the trick.

You don't need to know, how a state signals that it is ready. It is more important to know that the function in question is used as a state function than to know that it returns a bit variable.

Also I test macros before using. So I don't provide somebody with state machines that may show strange behavior.

Comment: Why not use a *function* instead of a macro?

Comment: Why use a macro at all? The first code sample is clear and straight forward. All the other ones just obscure the code (they don't look like valid C code) and you won't get any thanks from anyone else that needs to maintain it. Use a function if you really want to.

Comment: `Because I always do the exact same combination with every counter, I tend to type it one line.` That's just plain ugly code.

Comment: Swedgin -> Putting the code in one line is ugly, that's why I want a macro instead.
Konrad -> Using functions is often slower, especially with passing arguements.
Kaylum -> in this particular case it may be so, but macro's can increase readability. If you download some random library to get some I2C sensor to work, you only have to look for the example code so you  'can get the job done'. It is not needed at all to dig inside the library itself. Same can be perfectly true for macros. Code readability depends on the used syntax.

Comment: @basknippels `Because I always do the exact same combination with every counter` this screams for a function. As in a textbook example for refactoring into subfunctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I don't recommend using this solution.

I had a go at trying to make this into macro's. It is indeed possible but if it's faster, that's another question. As you make a new variable each time you call the macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define entryState(runOnce) int temp_state = runOnce; if (runOnce) runOnce = 0; if (temp_state)
#define timeExpired(someTimer, someInterval) int temp_expired = someTimer; if (!someTimer) someTimer = someInterval; if (!temp_expired)

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    int runOnce = 1;
    int someTimer = 0;
    int someInterval = 200;
    timeExpired(someTimer, someInterval) {
        printf("someTimer is Expired\n");
    }

    printf("someTimer: %i\n\n", someTimer);

    entryState(runOnce) {
        printf("this is running once\n");
    }

    printf("runOnce: %i\n", runOnce);

}
```

Compiling and running:

```
c:/repo $ gcc test.c -o test
c:/repo $ ./test.exe 
someTimer is Expired
someTimer: 200

this is running once
runOnce: 0
```

I don't have a C51 compiler at hand now, so I let the testing on the 8051 over to you.

Comment: Besides these macros being real ugly, this won't work in C90 since you couldn't declare variables in the middle of a block back then.

Comment: @Lundin shoot, you are right. My environment atm is C99 with xc32-gcc and there it's possible. And yeah, I totally agree, this solution is real ugly, but this is what OP asked.; added disclaimer

Comment: @Lundin I also think this is an XY problem. If we have the accompanied code/purpose of the program, maybe it becomes clear these macro's aren't needed at all and it's just rewriting a function.

Comment: splendid answer! @Lundin you are not getting the point at all. The macro definition may be ugly in your eyes. But the point is that you should not be looking at the definition in the first place. You just should be able to use it. For Arduino project I use their functions all the time. I never looked inside the actual function bodies. I don't have to. Every state of my state machines have 3 sections 'entryState', 'onState' and 'exitState'. The state function is also macro'ed into 
```State(aName) {
    // code 
}
```
There is no need to know how it works, as long as you can fill it in.

Comment: @basknippels Honestly if this is just for having to write less, I'd recommend you to look into an editor which can insert templates (like Emacs with yasnippet). Also, I'd post your working code in `codereview` as I'm quite sure by refactoring some functions you don't need the macros at all and can still do it in 1 line.

Comment: @basknippels No, that's exactly the point. You can hide your whole 1000 LoC code between some secret function-like macros `BLIP BLOP` and that's perfectly valid C. The problem is that _C programmers_ understand exactly what `if(!ledT) {  ledT = 200; ...` means. They _do not_ understand what the secret macro language `expired(ledT, 200) { ...` means. Only you do, right now. Some years from now, you won't understand it yourself either. Don't try to re-invent the extremely well standardized language.

Comment: Also. Due to variable declaration in mid block, c51 cannot compile unfortunately. Gcc however does. I can tell you that it is definately not faster, but that wasn't the goal.
@swedgin, the macros are not needed at all, but functions for this pupose are needed neither. My goal was to merge 2 lines of codes to reduce typing and to create better syntax. This may not be the result for the timers, but IMO it is the case for the entry state

Answer (score 5):

There’s no need to employ macros here, and doing so leads to highly un-idiomatic C code that doesn’t really have any advantages over proper C code.

Use a function instead:

```
int toggle_if_unset(int time, int pin, int interval) {
    if (time == 0) {
        time = 200;
        TOG(pin);
    }
    return time;
}
```

```
ledT = toggle_if_unset(ledT, ledPin, 200);
```

(I’m guessing appropriate parameter names based on your example; adjust as appropriate.)

What’s more, it looks as if `ledT` and `ledPin` are always paired and belong together, in which case you should consider putting them into a `struct`:

```
struct led {
    pin_t pin;
    int interval;
};

void toggle_if_unset(struct led *led, int new_interval);
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: ledT and ledPin are unlinked. I have a plain txt file which has all my software counters and their time bases. A python script generates the timers.c and timers.h files for me. So I only have to alter one location and run a script if a change in timers is needed.

"...and doing so leads to highly un-idiomatic C code that doesn’t really have any advantages over proper C code". Not true. Function calls are slower, especially if you start passing arguments. Whether a macro is less or more readable than a function solely depends on how they are written.

Comment: @basknippels There are quite a few misconceptions here. For example, “function calls are slower” — this is generally not true at all, and it would be best if you forgot this myth instantly. For instance, the function I’ve shown here will be trivially inlined by any optimiser worth its salt (= by *every* current compiler). In fact, I’d probably define it as `inline` in a header to make this easier. As a general rule, in modern C, you *never* want to use a macro as a substitute for a proper function. Use macros *only* when functions aren’t usable, i.e. for code generation and include guards.

Comment: @basknippels The fact that you are restricted to a non-conforming not-quite-C compiler should have been mentioned front and centre in your question.  Currently your question is tagged [tag:c]. My answer is the canonical answer for C. You want something different.

Comment: @basknippels Out of curiousity, why are you writing code for 40 years old hardware? Is it some retro computing project?

Comment: @Lundin because my friend, that device you typed your message from most likely has atleast one 8051 derivative in it. The things are still is in use. The thing I am actually programming is a cyclone V FPGA with... an 8051 softcore. Why? to reuse all existing code. We also still employ actual 8051 derivative chips today.

Comment: @basknippels I prefer giving helpful, educational answers over “technically correct” but misleading answers, and I strongly believe that this is the purpose of Stack Overflow. That’s why it’s so important to give all relevant context in questions.

Answer (score 4):

Given that this is for some old 8051 legacy project, it is *extremely unlikely* that you need to create abstraction layer macros for pin I/O handling. You'll only have just so many pins. Your original code is most likely the best and clearest one.

If you for some reason worry about code repetition, because you have multiple combinations of the product/support multiple PCB with different routing etc, and you are stuck with your current code base... then *as a last resort* you could use macros to avoid code repetition. This also assuming that you are a seasoned C programmer - otherwise stop reading here.

What you will be looking at in that rare scenario is probably something that's known as "X macros", which is about declaring a whole list of pre-processor constants. Then whenever you need to do something repetitive, you call upon that list and use the constants inside it that you are interested for that specific call. Each call is done by specifying what the macro "X" should do in that particular call, then undefined the macro afterwards.

For example if you have ports A, B, C, you have LEDs on port A:0, B:1 and C:2 respectively and wish to use different delays per pin, you can declare a list like this:

```
#define LED_LIST           \
/*  port   pin   delay */  \
  X(A,     0,    100)      \
  X(B,     1,    200)      \
  X(C,     2,    300)      \
```

Then you can call upon this list when you need to do repetitive tasks. For example if these ports have data direction registers you need to set accordingly and those registers are called DDRA, DDRB, DDRC (using Motorola/AVR naming as example):

```
/* set data direction registers */
#define X(port, pin, delay) DDR##port |= 1u<<pin;
  LED_LIST
#undef X
```

This will expand to:

```
DDRA |= 1u<<0;
DDRB |= 1u<<1;
DDRC |= 1u<<2;
```

Similarly, you can initialize the counters as:

```
/* declare counters */
#define X(port, delay) static uint16_t count##port = delay;
  LED_LIST
#undef X


...

/* check if counters elapsed */
#define X(port, delay) if(count##port == 0) { count##port = delay; PORT##port ^= 1u << pin; }
  LED_LIST
#undef X
```

(I replaced the toggle macro with a simple bitwise XOR)

Which will expand to:

```
static uint16_t countA = 100;
static uint16_t countB = 200;
static uint16_t countC = 300;

...

if(countA == 0) 
{ 
  countA = 100; 
  PORTA ^= 1u << 0; 
}
if(countB == 0) 
{ 
  countB = 200; 
  PORTB ^= 1u << 1; 
}
if(countC == 0) 
{ 
  countC = 300; 
  PORTC ^= 1u << 2; 
}
```

And of course avoid using 16 bit counters like done here unless you must, since you are working with a crappy 8-bitter.

Comment: I have updated the question. I do not understand how anyone came to think that the question is about toggling IO. I do not care about IO, I just used one as an example.
It is al bout merging 2 code lines in a single line of code with a macro.

Comment: @basknippels Regardless, this same macro scheme is completely generic. "X macros" is mostly used for avoiding repetition while maintaining existing code bases.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define LL(ledT) do {if(!ledT) { ledT = 200; TOG(ledPin); }}while(0)
```

> Whilst reading about macros, I've read something interesting about
>   using: do ... while(0). This 'trick' abuses the compiler's
>   optimization feature to create a certain macro, which would otherwise
>   be impossible.

Most of the opinions there are actually wrong. There is nothing about optimizations.

The main reason is to make macros using curled braces to compile at all.

This one will not compile

```
#define A(x) {foo(x);bar(x);}

void foo1(int x)
{
    if (x) A(1);
       else B(0);
}
```

but this one will compile

```
#define A(x) do{foo(x);bar(x);}while(0)

void foo1(int x)
{
    if (x) A(1);
       else B(0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4jH2jP

Comment: About optimalization: as far as I understand. The C code we write get's transformerd into assembly code and/or machine code. Things like if(0) {body} would be removed entirely because the compiler understands it cannot ever be executed. Same goes for while(0). It won't be translated to actual machine code afaik.

Comment: @basknippels `*Same goes for while(0)*` I do not understand what you mean, but generally not. `}while(` is checked after the statements in the curly braces.

Comment: Also, your first macro does not do the trick unfortunately. The thing is that TOG(ledPin) can be anything. That particular line is ment to be behind the macro in curly brackets so that it can be anything. I am also not even sure if what I want is even possible. Atleast thank you for your efforts so far.

Comment: @basknippels I do not understand your comment.It does not make any sense

Comment: Many would say that using `if ... else` without braces is always bad style and the compiler error you get when not using the do-while(0) trick is a good thing.

Comment: @Lundin I only explain retionale behind the do {} while(0)

Comment: `0` is an integral constant expression, so `while(0)` can be [evaluated at compile-time](https://godbolt.org/z/p7XEGp).

Comment: @HWalters and statements in the curly braces will be executed once.  Remember we talk about `do{...}while(0)` not about `while(0){...}`

Comment: Okay, I think we're just reading this differently.  I'm reading "Same goes for `while(0)`" as talking about the `while(0)` part per se (as in, bas is saying just as an entire if(0) is elided, the while(0) check is); you're reading it as applying to the entire `do{`/`}while(0)` loop (as in, he's saying just as an if(0) is elided, a do{} while(0) is).